# What is the relationship between ShapeRange, Chart, ChartArea, & PlotArea

Tags: excel, excel-interop, excel-charts

Ok, so a ChartObject has a Chart & ShapeRange member. And a Chart has a ChartArea and PlotArea member:

1. What exactly is the Chart member? It say's it "represents" the chart - what does that mean?
2. Is the ShapeRange a range the ChartObject holds? And if so, what can be in it? Or is it a parent range that the ChartObject is in?
3. The ChartArea says it's the "chart area." What is that?
4. The PlotArea says it's the "plot area." What is that?
5. This example shows setting a Series.ChartArea but the documentation does not show ChartArea as a Series property. Can ChartArea (and PlotArea) be set in a Series? And if so, what does that mean?

thanks - dave

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us the link to "This example"?

Comment: [Found the example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456769.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much help this will be, here are answers for 2 of your questions:

3. The **chart area** is the entire area used by the chart, including axis labels, legends, title, etc. If you select a chart, then hover your mouse over i, you will see is labeled:

[image]

4. The **plot area** is the area used by the chart itself, excluding axis labels, legends, title, etc. Once you've selected a chart, you can select the plot area. Again hovering your mouse over it, will label it:

[image]